# Start Wine program using nVidia video card

Tags: nvidia, wine, video, bumblebee, photoshop

I recent have installed Adobe Photoshop CS6 using Wine. If I run in terminal `optirun wine 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Photoshop.exe"` I get the next errors :

```
vas@LenovoZ580:~$ optirun wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Photoshop.exe"
err:module:attach_process_dlls "msvcp90.dll" failed to initialize, aborting
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Adobe Photoshop CS6\\Photoshop.exe" failed, status c0000005
```

If I try without `optirun` the program starts. I use Ubuntu 13.04 and Wine 1.4. Can I start windows programs with Wine using nVidia discrete video card?

Comment: I would suggest going to the wineHQ forums and search for `msvcp90.dll`. Example: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.wine.user/88226 3 of the installers for PS mention that you need to get a copy of `msvcp90.dll`. To me this has no relation to Ubuntu though ;)

Comment: It don't work. I find other solution on google and didn't find anything.

Comment: the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solutin is : `primusrun wine "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Photoshop.exe"`